# How do I stop my Highcharts columns from changing width?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Dear Highcharts experts,

I have a Highcharts column plot that includes the ability to sort the order of the data points in various ways:

http://jsfiddle.net/9phfzewj/41/

This seems to work well. However, during some of the sort transitions the data points increase in width. I don't want this to happen, but don't understand why it takes place.

For example, clicking on "Ascending DLP" works fine, but if you then click on "Descending frequency" then the correct sort takes place, but the width of all the points increases. Clicking on "Alphabetical" makes the points revert back to their correct width.

Is anyone able to offer any help? It would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

David

```js
$(function () {
    var chart;
    var defaultTitle = "CT doses";
    var protocolNames = ['Abdomen','Thorax','Sinus'];
    var frequencies = [120,300,250];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                drilldown: function(e) {
                    parentSeriesIndex = e.point.series.index;
                    parentSeriesName = e.point.series.name;
                    chart.setTitle({ text:''});
                    chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({text:'Number'});
                    chart.xAxis[0].setTitle({text:'DLP range (mGy.cm)'});
                    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories([], true);
                    chart.tooltip.options.formatter = function(args) {
                        returnValue =  this.y.toFixed(0) + ', DLP series' + ', ' + this.x;
                        return returnValue;
                    };
                },
                drillup: function(e) {
                    chart.setTitle({ text: defaultTitle }, { text: '' });
                    chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({text:'DLP (mGy.cm)'});
                    chart.xAxis[0].setTitle({text:''});
                    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(protocolNames, true);
                    chart.xAxis[0].update({labels:{rotation:90}});
                    chart.tooltip.options.formatter = function(args) {
                var index = protocolNames.indexOf(this.x);
                var comment = this.x + '<br/>' + this.y.toFixed(1) + ' mGy.cm' + '<br/>(n=' + frequencies[index] + ')';
                return comment;
                    };
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'CT doses'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            type: "category",
            categories: protocolNames,
            labels: {
                rotation:90
            }
        }],
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'DLP (mGy.cm)'
            }
        }],
        legend: {
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 0,
            y: 70
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                var index = protocolNames.indexOf(this.x);
                var comment = this.x + '<br/>' + this.y.toFixed(1) + ' mGy.cm' + '<br/>(n=' + frequencies[index] + ')';
                return comment;
            },
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'DLP',
            data: [{
                name: 'Abdomen',
                y: 150,
                freq: 120,
                drilldown: 'AbdomenDLP'
            }, {
                name: 'Thorax',
                y: 73,
                freq: 300,
                drilldown: 'ThoraxDLP'
            }, {
                name: 'Sinus',
                y: 20,
                freq: 250,
                drilldown: 'SinusDLP'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mGy.cm'
            }
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Abdomen DLP',
                id: 'AbdomenDLP',
                data: [
                    ['up to 150', 4],
                    ['up to 200', 2],
                    ['up to 250', 1],
                    ['up to 300', 2],
                    ['up to 350', 1]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Thorax DLP',
                id: 'ThoraxDLP',
                data: [
                    ['up to 100', 40],
                    ['up to 110', 21],
                    ['up to 120', 24],
                    ['up to 130', 32],
                    ['up to 140', 64]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Sinus DLP',
                id: 'SinusDLP',
                data: [
                    ['up to 130', 4],
                    ['up to 140', 2],
                    ['up to 150', 6],
                    ['up to 160', 7],
                    ['up to 170', 9]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
        
    $('#sort').click(function() {
  chart.series[0].data.sort(function(a, b) {
   return b.y > a.y;
  });
        rebuildSeries();
    });
        
    $('#sort2').click(function() {
  chart.series[0].data.sort(function(a, b) {
   return b.y < a.y;
  });
        rebuildSeries();
    });

    $('#sort3').click(function() {
  chart.series[0].data.sort(function(a, b) {
   return b.category < a.category;
  });

        rebuildSeries();
    });

    $('#sort4').click(function() {
  chart.series[0].data.sort(function(a, b) {
   return b.category > a.category;
  });
        rebuildSeries();
    });

    $('#sort5').click(function() {
  chart.series[0].data.sort(function(a, b) {
   return b.freq < a.freq;
  });
        rebuildSeries();
    });

    $('#sort6').click(function() {
  chart.series[0].data.sort(function(a, b) {
   return b.freq > a.freq;
  });
        rebuildSeries();
    });
        
    function rebuildSeries() {
        var newData = {};
        var newCategories = [];
            
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
            newData.x = i;
            newData.y = chart.series[0].data[i].y;
            newData.category = chart.series[0].data[i].category;
            newData.drilldown = chart.series[0].data[i].drilldown;
            newData.name = chart.series[0].data[i].name;
            newData.freq = chart.series[0].data[i].freq;
            newCategories.push(chart.series[0].data[i].category);
            chart.series[0].data[i].update(newData, false);
        }
        chart.xAxis[0].categories = newCategories;
        chart.redraw({ duration: 1000 });
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://highslide-software.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

Sort by clicking on one of the options below:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a id="sort2">Ascending DLP</a></td>
        <td><a id="sort">Descending DLP</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a id="sort3">Alphabetical</a></td>
        <td><a id="sort4">Reverse alphabetical</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a id="sort5">Frequency</a></td>
        <td><a id="sort6">Reverse frequency</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem is you are sorting inner array of Highcharts data. I think it's coincidence it works at all. Instead, you should be using separate dataset to update points, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9phfzewj/45/ (note animation is different, but this is expected).